# history listen is not working for react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react class called `App`

I have the following code in my render method:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Content>
        <ListItem onClick={this.onListItemClick}
      <Content>
    </div>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

Inside `onListItemClick` I am doing `history.push(location);`

These are the following import statements I have in my code:

```
import { Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
```

Then I am creating and listening to history as follows:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
history.listen(location, action => {
  console.log('listen triggered');
});
```

I have the following export statements.

```
export {App, AppState etc}
export default App
```

The console log statement is never logged.

How to make sure that the `history.listen` is triggered everytime correctly?

Versions:

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"history": "^4.7.2",
```

Comment: You probably should use `BrowserRouter` instead of the generic `Router`. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: Actually this seems like a bug.

Comment: I believe it's happening since react-router overrides listen with it's own: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js#L62. Feel free to file a bug. You can use this sandbox as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vyy7xo9oy